# Слишком медленная анимация при изменении коллекции ListView в UWP

Tags: c#, listview, анимация, uwp

Есть совершенно стандартный ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="lst">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="logic:UIItem">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

которому в коде C# задана коллекция ObservableCollection в качестве ItemsSource.
При изменении коллекции анимация слишком долгая (красиво, но такая низкая скорость мало подходит). Быстрее происходит полная смена коллекции, чем добавление в нее 1 элемента.

Имею ввиду стандартную анимацию, зашитую в элемент управления.

Аналогичная ситуация, если изменять коллекцию элементов через, например, lst.Items.Add(dataItem).

Буду рад идеям, как ее можно ускорить ее или вовсе отключить..

Comment: Это: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13559410/276994?

Comment: @VladD, да, очень похоже, надо будет разобраться, спасибо Вам! Отпишусь по результатам

Answer (score 1):

В итоге получилось следующее решение (спасибо VladD):

```
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <!--<AddDeleteThemeTransition />-->
                        <ContentThemeTransition/>
                        <ReorderThemeTransition/>
                        <EntranceThemeTransition />
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>
```

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, вы просто выключили анимацию вот этим `<AddDeleteThemeTransition />` ? И почему у вас это закомментировано?

Comment: @Bulson Отключил анимацию добавлением стиля и комментированием этой строки..